# How do i match data using mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

**Need some help**
I have 5 tables in the database, here is the mysql code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `candidate` (
  `CID` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `phone_num` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `regdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `acc_type` enum('c','s') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'c',
  `emailactivate` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cv_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `cv` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='// this is the table for the candidates' AUTO_INCREMENT=175 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `candidate_skill`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `candidate_skill` (
  `CSID` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CID` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `S_CODE` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CSID`),
  KEY `CID` (`CID`),
  KEY `S_CODE` (`S_CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='//match candidate and skill' AUTO_INCREMENT=102 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `job`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `job` (
  `JID` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job_title` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `job_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='// this is the table for the job vacancies' AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `skill`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skill` (
  `S_CODE` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '// this is the skill primary key',
  `skill_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `skill_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`S_CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `skill_job`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skill_job` (
  `SJID` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `JID` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `S_CODE` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SJID`),
  KEY `S_CODE` (`S_CODE`),
  KEY `JID` (`JID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=94 ;
```

And this is the query giving me problems:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM candidate, candidate_skill, job, skill, skill_job WHERE candidate_skill.S_CODE=skill_job.S_CODE AND skill.S_CODE=candidate_skill.S_CODE AND candidate.CID=candidate_skill.CID AND job.JID = skill_job.JID");

$result = mysql_query ($query);
$candidate_id ='';      
$canskill ='';
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_array ($res)){
            $candidate_id .= $r['CID'];
            $canskill .= $r ['S_CODE'];


            }
        }


        }
    echo $candidate_id;
```

I'm trying to match candidates and jobs using their skills and i have sort of succeeded but im having candidates match with jobs even if they only have one skill and the job has for example three skills.
Can someone please point me in the right direction because I have searched, tested and recoded for days but im failing to move past this problem

Answer (score 0):

you're doing a simple join, so any candidate who has even just one of the listed skills will be matched. You need to actually count how many of required skills are matched, and filter the query results using that.

Without rejiggering your whole query, it'd be something like:

```
SELECT ..., COUNT(skill_job.id) AS cnt
FROM ....
WHERE ...
HAVING (cnt = 3)
```

This'd restrict to candidates who have exactly 3 of the required skills. If you want "at least 2" or similar types, then it'd be

```
HAVING (cnt >= 2)
```

and so one for other variations.

Comment: can you let me know how i could reorganize the whole query?